# uniform convergence!(series of a function)

Tags: real-analysis

show whether or not the series $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1+xn^{\frac{1}{2}}}{n(1+nx)}$ on $[1,+ \infty )$ is uniformly convergent.

weierstress m-test failed on $[1,+ \infty )$, 
dirichlet's test not sure because i got confuse and
abel's test passed. I maybe wrong, pls somebody help me check, thanks

Answer (score 1):

I believe Weierstrass' M-test works.

We have $$\frac{1+x\sqrt n}{n(1+nx)}=n^{\frac{-3}2}+\frac{1-\frac1{\sqrt n}}{n(1+nx)}\leq n^{\frac{-3}2}+n^{-2}$$
if $x\geq1$.

Can you continue from here?